# If you're hourly employee don't finish job during shift, do you have to finish it off the clock? (United States)

Tags: united-states, hourly

If you're hourly employee don't finish job during shift, do you have to finish it off the clock? How to reply no I won't do it.

Comment: If you at at risk, and you should have finished it during regular working hours, and it's a small amount of work, my recommendation is you just do it.

Comment: (user posted a second, near-identical question.)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question is about retaliation by giving you fewer hours.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read up on Wage Theft.

If you are being 'asked' to work for free, you can decline. If you can get it in writing and you are fired, even in an at-will state, that would be wrongful termination.

If you are working for the company, they should be paying for your time.

The only exception would be where you took a leave of absence *during the time you were still clocked in* and you were making up time later on.

e.g. You leave to pick up your kids from school, you didn't clock out and because of that, you didn't finish the work and you are merely making up time.

Comment: This. You MUST be paid for the time you work in the US, no exceptions. The proper way to handle the "still clocked in picking up my kids" situation is with a timecard adjustment, not unpaid labor later in equivalence. This is due to insurance/workman's comp and legal compliance.

Comment: @GOATNine: On principle I agree with you. Folks on hourly wage maybe forced to trade off that principle against retaining the job, unfortunately. If it's only one or two instances a year and only 15 minutes additional work each time, it may not be worth arguing about, especially if the employee *should* have finished the task earlier.  Certainly salaried folks often work a few extra hours at no additional pay, trading that against good performance ratings and (ideally) some informal flex-time.